# Setting up Weka in Eclipse for code analysis(design smells,patterns,metrics and possible improvements)

Tags: eclipse, oop, weka

I have an assignment of analysing an Object Oriented system and I have chosen [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) for that. I am trying to analyse the source code for metrics and patterns using plugins present in eclipse but I am not able to set up the source code of WEKA for that (lots of errors). I am having issues with setting up the source code (weka-src.jar) in eclipse.

Can anyone tell me how to set up the source code as a project in eclipse and to use the plugins for analysing and evaluating the code?

I am planning to use Eclipse metrics plugin and it would be great if you could suggest more tools for OO analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use weka-src.jar , checkout from [subversion](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/) source code repository. This code has necessary setup for eclipse (.classpath and .project files).

Do following after you checkout subversion code.

- File-> Import Existing Project into workspace
- Choose directory which contains setup for eclipse (.classpath and .project files)

Comment: so how am i supposed to download those files?

Comment: look for a basic subversion tutorial

Comment: I have downloaded the code. It would be really helpful if you could tell how to set the code up in eclipse.